# Playing Video using MediaCodec and OpenGl ES creates a delay

Tags: android, opengl-es, video-streaming, video-processing, android-mediacodec

I am trying to play a video from a file using MediaCodec to decode the file and OpenGl to apply wanted changes, I successfully wrote a code that plays the video and  add the wanted changes... It works well on short and low quality video... I tested on 1080P 2:42 minutes video but the total play time in the app is 3:08 minutes

How does the code work, I generate a SurfaceTexture from an TextureView inside the XML code and passe it to the EGLDisplay

This is how I create The EGLContext:

```
eglDisplay = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
    if (eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY)
        throw RuntimeException("eglDisplay == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY: " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))

    val version = IntArray(2)
    if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(eglDisplay, version, 0, version, 1))
        throw RuntimeException("eglInitialize(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))

    val attribList = intArrayOf(
        EGL14.EGL_RED_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
        EGLExt.EGL_RECORDABLE_ANDROID, 1,
        EGL14.EGL_NONE)
    val configs = arrayOfNulls<EGLConfig>(1)
    val nConfigs = IntArray(1)
    if (!EGL14.eglChooseConfig(eglDisplay, attribList, 0, configs, 0, configs.size, nConfigs, 0)) throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))

    var err = EGL14.eglGetError()
    if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

    val ctxAttribs = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2, EGL14.EGL_NONE)
    eglContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(eglDisplay, configs[0], EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, ctxAttribs, 0)

    err = EGL14.eglGetError()
    if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

    val surfaceAttribs = intArrayOf(EGL14.EGL_NONE)
    eglSurface = EGL14.eglCreateWindowSurface(eglDisplay, configs[0], textureViewGeneratedFromSurface, surfaceAttribs, 0)
    err = EGL14.eglGetError()
    if (err != EGL14.EGL_SUCCESS) throw RuntimeException(GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(err))

    if (!EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(eglDisplay, eglSurface, eglSurface, eglContext))
        throw RuntimeException("eglMakeCurrent(): " + GLUtils.getEGLErrorString(EGL14.eglGetError()))
```

this is how i create the textures to handle decoding and encoding

```
surfaceTexture = SurfaceTexture(videoRenderer!!.texId)
        thread = HandlerThread("FrameHandlerThread")
        thread!!.start()

        surfaceTexture!!.setOnFrameAvailableListener({
            synchronized(lock) {
                // New frame available before the last frame was process...we dropped some frames
                if (frameAvailable) Log.d(TAG, "Frame available before the last frame was process...we dropped some frames")
                frameAvailable = true
                lock.notifyAll()
            }
        }, Handler(thread!!.looper))
        outputSurface = Surface(surfaceTexture)
```

this is how i play the video:

```
encoder!!.configure(outputVideoFormat, null, null, MediaCodec.CONFIGURE_FLAG_ENCODE)
        inputSurface = encoder!!.createInputSurface()
        decoder!!.configure(inputVideoFormat!!, outputSurface, null, 0)
        encoder!!.start()
        decoder!!.start()
        allInputExtracted = false
        allInputDecoded = false
        allOutputEncoded = false
        val videoStartDebugTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        while (!allOutputEncoded) {
            // Feed input to decoder
            if (!allInputExtracted)
              feedInputToDecoder()

            var encoderOutputAvailable = true
            var decoderOutputAvailable = !allInputDecoded

            while (decoderOutputAvailable) {
                if (!allInputDecoded) {
                    val outBufferId = decoder!!.dequeueOutputBuffer(bufferInfo, mediaCodedTimeoutUs)
                    if (outBufferId >= 0) {
                        var render = bufferInfo.size > 0
                        if (firstFrame){
                            firstFrameShownIn = System.currentTimeMillis();
                            firstFrame = false
                        }
                        val sleepTime: Long = (bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs) / 1000 - (System.currentTimeMillis() - firstFrameShownIn)
                        if (sleepTime > 0 ){
                            delay(sleepTime)
                        }
                        decoder!!.releaseOutputBuffer(outBufferId, render)
                        if (render) {
                            waitTillFrameAvailable()

                            surfaceTexture!!.updateTexImage()
                            surfaceTexture!!.getTransformMatrix(texMatrix)

                            // Draw texture with opengl
                            GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT or GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
                            GLES20.glClearColor(0f, 0f, 0f, 0f)
                            GLES20.glViewport((width - outputVideoWidth) / 2, (height - outputVideoHeight) / 2, outputVideoWidth, outputVideoHeight)

                            videoRenderer?.draw(getMVP(), texMatrix, null)
                            textAnimator.update()
                            textRenderer!!.draw(textAnimator.getMVP(), null,
                                textToBitmap("TEST", outputVideoWidth, outputVideoHeight)
                            )
                            EGLExt.eglPresentationTimeANDROID(eglDisplay, eglSurface,
                                bufferInfo.presentationTimeUs * 1000)

                            EGL14.eglSwapBuffers(eglDisplay, eglSurface)
                        }
                        // Did we get all output from decoder?
                        if ((bufferInfo.flags and MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM) != 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG+"@@@@","Video Total time: ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - videoStartDebugTime) / 1000} SEC, Video Total time: ${(System.currentTimeMillis() - videoStartDebugTime)}")
                            allInputDecoded = true
                            encoder!!.signalEndOfInputStream()
                        }
                    } else if (outBufferId == MediaCodec.INFO_TRY_AGAIN_LATER) {
                        decoderOutputAvailable = false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        encoder!!.stop()
        decoder!!.stop()
```

feedInputToDecoder function:

```
val inBufferId = decoder!!.dequeueInputBuffer(mediaCodedTimeoutUs)
    if (inBufferId >= 0) {
        val buffer = decoder!!.getInputBuffer(inBufferId)
        val sampleSize = extractor!!.readSampleData(buffer!!, 0)
        if (sampleSize >= 0) {
            decoder!!.queueInputBuffer(inBufferId, 0, sampleSize,
                extractor!!.sampleTime, extractor!!.sampleFlags)
            extractor!!.advance()

        } else {
            decoder!!.queueInputBuffer(inBufferId, 0, 0,
                0, MediaCodec.BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM)
            allInputExtracted = true
        }
    }
```

waitTillFrameAvailable() function:

```
synchronized(lock) {
        while (!frameAvailable) {
            lock.wait(200)
            if (!frameAvailable)
                Log.d(TAG,"Surface frame wait timed out")
        }
        frameAvailable = false
    }
```

It  worked fine with the short low quality video after I set mediaCodedTimeoutUs = 0, But now there's a delay and I don't know from where... What can I improve ?